# select into a table using a variable as table name dynamic sql not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute the code below (I know a lot of people have already asked this question but none of them worked for me). since I have a loop I need to select into multiple new tables with the value of variable name as tables names.
I tried using dynamic sql for the tables name like this:

```
WHILE ( @Counter <= @len)
begin
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(10),@sql nvarchar(max)
SET @name= (select  product from @ProductType where  NewPK= @Counter)
set @sql='
    select m=DATEPART(month,t2.initial_date),y=DATEPART(year,t2.initial_date) ,t1.user_orders,t1.account_id
    into  '+@name+'
    from (select dbo.sales_info.account_id, count(*) as user_orders
        from dbo.sales_info 
        where dbo.sales_info.product= @name
        group by dbo.sales_info.account_id) t1
    left join 
    (select dbo.sales_info.account_id, initial_date= min( dbo.sales_info.start_date)
    from dbo.sales_info group by dbo.sales_info.start_date,dbo.sales_info.account_id )t2
    on t1.account_id=t2.account_id
    order by m,y'
exec (@sql)
SET @Counter = @Counter  + 1
end
```

but I keep getting this error :

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@name".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@name".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query for set the name value return a valid result??

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server - pick the one you are actually using. If SQL Server - stop the nonsense about using a counter and a while loop. If you need a cursor, then just use a cursor. And stop cramming your code together. Make an effort to be understood. Develop good habits. Lastly - on which line does the error occur? No one can run your code. There is an obvious mistake in your dynamically generated SQL - you will see it if you print or select it before executing it.

Comment: yes, I'm using @name in WHERE statement and it works for that part

Comment: There is no DATEPART function in MySQL

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the code is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: `exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@name varchar(10)', @name = @name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
where dbo.sales_info.product = @name
```

You can use parameters when you execute the code:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@name varchar(10),
                   @name=@name;
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the massive injection issue you have though @Sana.Nz . `@Name` is at least a `varchar(10)` but you should never inject raw strings into a dynamic statement. Always properly quote your object names with `QUOTENAME`.